# Rows with specific relationship between columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose, I have a mysql table "MyTable" with the following content

```
-----------------------
| Column 1 | Column 2 | 
-----------------------
|    1     |    a     |
-----------------------
|    1     |    b     |
-----------------------
|    2     |    a     |
-----------------------
|    2     |    a     |
-----------------------
|    3     |    a     |
-----------------------
|    4     |    b     |
-----------------------
|    4     |    a     |
-----------------------
```

I would like to get the values in Column 1 where the values in the Column 1 does not pair only with 'a' such that the results is

```
------------
|  Result  | 
------------
|    1     |
------------
|    4     |
------------
```

because the values 2 and 3 pair only with 'a' (whether there is only 1 pair or multiple pairs with 'a' does not matter).

**Note:** I don't know what are the possible values in Column 2 - I just would like to avoid pairing with only 'a'. Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: "does not pair only with 'a'" - is it required that it "pairs" with 'a'?

Comment: convert your english statement to sql -- group by column 1, count how many distinct items in column2 are there for each group, and then filter groups where count > 1.

Comment: Perhaps... `SELECT DISTINCT column1 FROM table WHERE column2 <> 'a'`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel: no, it is not necessary to pairs with 'a'. I will try to translate the sql queries that I have tried to something generic here. This question is actually a simplified version of my actual problem. I kept running into an error: Given correlated subquery is not supported.

Comment: @Lam: perhaps you are loking for something like this `select distinct col1 from weird w where
(select count(distinct col2) from weird w2 where w.col1 = w2.col1)  > 1`

Comment: @JNevill: actually you are right! it turns out to be simpler than I thought :D.. sorry everyone for not clarifying if pairing with 'a' is required.

Comment: @Strawberry: for instance.. if there are multiple rows of 2 - a and 1 row of 3 - a.. I would exclude all of them because both 2 and 3 pair only with a.. sorry if I am confusing..

Comment: @Strawberry: yup.. suppose there is another data: 5 - b, i am ok with getting 5

Comment: @Strawberry: nope, that's not the question. I just don't want anything that pairs only with a. If it pairs with a, b, c, ..., that's fine. If it pairs with b, c, d, ..., that's fine too. JNevill's answer does the simple trick.

Comment: You are looking for values from `col1` that pairs with at least two values from `col2` is that right?

Comment: @mohessaid: "I would like to get the values in Column 1 where the values in the Column 1 does not pair only with 'a' "

Comment: So values from `col1` that pair with `a` and another value from `col2`. means the values that don't pair with `a` are excluded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT DISTINCT column_1 FROM my_table WHERE column_2 <> 'a';`

Comment: Yes, JNevill should take the credit for this one!!!! Well done for divining that what the OP asked for, and what they actually wanted, were two different things.

Answer (score 1):

You could check for the column1 that having count(distinct column2 ) = 2

```
select column1 
from my_table 
where column1 in (
  select column1
  from my_tbale 
  group by column1
  having count(distinct column2) =2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1 from your_table t1 WHERE
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT col2) from your_table t2 WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col1)  > 1
```

This way you will be sure that the values you are getting from `col1` are associated with more than one value from `col2`.
You can also get the result for values from `col1` which are associated with all the values from `col2`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1 from your_table t1 WHERE
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT col2) from your_table t2 WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col1)  = 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT col2) from your_table t3)
```

Comment: @Strawberry: You can optimize it if you have an idea :), I tried and it worked. Sometimes there is no optimized solution using SQL only. That's why we assist our queries with code. The number of unique values can be saved as key if he is using a caching system or views or whatever. I suggested this answer and it's arguable.